# How do U.S. lawyers meet file retention standards?

Tags: united-states, evidence

U.S. lawyers have to keep clients files for (six?) years.

What are accepted standards of file/document retention? Suppose they keep all their files in locked cabinets in an office building and there's a fire or earthquake that destroys the files. Has the lawyer done enough to protect the files despite "losing" them? Or are they required to add offsite and/or electronic backup?

Put another way, are U.S. lawyers held to "strict liability" for file retention or is it more of a "reasonable efforts" standard?

Answer (score 1):

This will vary by state. An excerpt from guidelines published by the Pennsylvania Bar Association, which quotes another ABA document, says in pertinent part:

> Going beyond the issue of what is the client's property, and directly addressing the
>   retention and destruction of files, the American Bar Association Committee on Ethics and
>   Professional Responsibility has stated:
>
> How to deal with the burden is primarily a question of business management, and
>   not primarily a question of ethics or professional responsibility. A lawyer does not
>   have a general duty to preserve all of his files permanently. Mounting and
>   substantial storage costs can affect the cost of legal services, and the public
>   interest is not served by unnecessary and avoidable additions to the costs of legal
>   services. But clients and former clients reasonably expect from their lawyers that
>   valuable and useful information in the lawyers files and not otherwise readily
>   available to the clients will not be prematurely and carelessly destroyed, to the
>   client's detriment.... We cannot say there is a specific time period during which a
>   lawyer must preserve all files.... Good common sense should provide answers to
>   most questions that arise.
>
> ABA Standing Committee on Ethics and Professional Responsibility, Informal
>   Opinion 1384 (1977).
>
> A thorough reading of the articles published in legal professional journals and periodicals
>   on file retention and destruction reveals the following recurring, common
>   recommendations:
>
> 1. Lawyers and law firms should develop a detailed file storage, management and
>      retention policy and should follow the policy consistently. The policy should address the
>      return to the client upon the conclusion of the matter, case or transaction of all original
>      documents such as business records, deeds, estate papers, title insurance policies and
>      abstracts, and papers personal to the client. Such a policy should further include the
>      direction of a closing letter to clients which notifies them of their entitlement to take any
>      documents not previously furnished to them and may advise of a date on which the file
>      will be destroyed in a manner which will protect the client's confidentiality.
> 2. The decision on how and when to destroy part or all of a file should be made by a
>      lawyer, not by an office manager, paralegal or other staff person.

[Available here.](http://padisciplinaryboard.org/documents/FO99-120.pdf)

[This 2003 document from the ABA](https://www.americanbar.org/content/dam/aba/migrated/buslaw/newsletter/0021/materials/recordretention.authcheckdam.pdf)  discusses the topic at length, as well.